# Advantages of differing ways of showing a Line in imagej

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I have created a line in imagej using the imageprocessor drawLine() method. I have also noticed that there exists a Line class.

I don't have too experience in imagej and was wondering what the advantage of using one method over the other would be?

Also if I were to use the Line class, how do I go about changing the colour of the Line

Thanks in advance

Bateman

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is

drawLine() :  The method ImageProcessor.drawLine() will change the pixel values in the displayed ImageProcessor.

The Line class extends ROI and so inherits all the properties of a ROI. You can measure the profile on it.

It really depends on what you are trying to do. Do you want to measure the values or do you want to change the pixel values to show something? If you are using stacks then the ROI will be present on each image in the stack. The drawLine() method is only called on one imageProcessor so only one image in the stack is affected.

If you use the Line class you can change pixel values by calling the method Fill. The colour (pixel value) can be edited by changing the value used to fill. You can also change the colour of the ROI line.

Using the drawLine() method set the colour on the ImageProcessor e.g setColor(Color.WHITE);